# Powershell count groups of items based on substring

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have an array of data gleaned from a command that contains several elements. Each item's name element starts with a three or four character identifier followed by a hyphen. I would like to get a count of all items in the array that contains the same identifier.

Data gathered with the following PowerCLI (VMware) command:

```
$items = Get-Datastore <Datastore Name> | Get-VM
```

Data example:

```
NAME     STATUS     INFO     DETAIL
ABC-1234-XXXX     PoweredOn     Info     Detail
ABC-1235-XXXX     PoweredOn     Info     Detail
ABC-1236-XXXX     PoweredOn     Info     Detail
BCA-1234-XXXX     PoweredOn     Info     Detail
BCA-1235-XXXX     PoweredOn     Info     Detail
CBA-1234-XXXX     PoweredOn     Info     Detail
CBA-1235-XXXX     PoweredOn     Info     Detail
CBA-1236-XXXX     PoweredOn     Info     Detail
CBA-1237-XXXX     PoweredOn     Info     Detail
```

I'd like the script to give me something like the following:

```
NAME     COUNT
ABC     3
BCA     2
CBA     4
```

I really don't have a code example, but I've considered using the PowerShell "group" method in conjunction with the count method. I'm struggling  with how to combine everything into something usable.

Group:

```
$array = $items | Group Name
```

Count:

```
$array.count
```

EDIT: Added data gathering command

Comment: Is your table from a powershell command or some other executable that's unstructured?

Comment: The answer will depend upon how you are getting that data (please update your question such that it answers @TheIncorrigible1's question).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: Question updated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are close, but you don't want to group by the complete name - you want to split `name` at - and take only the first [0] element.

This can be done `on the fly` inside a {script block} as a calculated property. Here the group is the desired outcome, in other cases (sorting on an otherwise not existing property) it doesn't leave traces in present data.

This shows stepwise the transformation of your data:

```
$items = Get-Datastore <Datastore Name> | Get-VM
$Items
```

---

```
NAME          STATUS    INFO DETAIL
----          ------    ---- ------
ABC-1234-XXXX PoweredOn Info Detail
ABC-1235-XXXX PoweredOn Info Detail
ABC-1236-XXXX PoweredOn Info Detail
BCA-1234-XXXX PoweredOn Info Detail
BCA-1235-XXXX PoweredOn Info Detail
CBA-1234-XXXX PoweredOn Info Detail
CBA-1234-XXXX PoweredOn Info Detail
CBA-1234-XXXX PoweredOn Info Detail
CBA-1234-XXXX PoweredOn Info Detail
```

---

```
$Items | Group-Object {$_.Name.Split('-')[0]}
```

---

```
Count Name Group
----- ---- -----
    3 ABC  {@{NAME=ABC-1234-XXXX; STATUS=PoweredOn; INFO=Info; DETAIL=Detail}, ...
    2 BCA  {@{NAME=BCA-1234-XXXX; STATUS=PoweredOn; INFO=Info; DETAIL=Detail}, ...
    4 CBA  {@{NAME=CBA-1234-XXXX; STATUS=PoweredOn; INFO=Info; DETAIL=Detail}, ...
```

---

```
$Items | Group-Object {$_.Name.Split('-')[0]} | Select-Object Name,Count
```

---

```
Name Count
---- -----
ABC      3
BCA      2
CBA      4
```

**Edit using Group-Object -NoElement would have left only the reordering for the last step**

Comment: This is a good method but it would be a great answer if you included explanation about what's happening (grouping on a scriptblock (constructed property), etc.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, LotPings. I was able to take your line and insert it into a larger script that did what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

If your array of items is called `$items` and the column is `Name` then this should work.

`$items | %{($_.Name -split "-")[0]} | group | select Name,Count`

Deconstructed, you're piping the elements to `ForEach-Object`, where you are splitting the `$_.Name` by the character `-`, taking the first element and passing that to `Group-Object`, then selecting the `Name` and `Count` properties.

Comment: The ForEach isn't neccessary, you can group by a calculated property.

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know that.

Comment: Great answer. I chose LotPing's answer because it was more correct.